# Time between 2 dates at the beginning of each day

Tags: java, time, duration, days

I have written the following code:

```
public static int getDaysTillActivation() {
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    int day = ZonedDateTime.now(z).getDayOfMonth();

    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {

        if (day % 2 == 0) {
            return i;
        }

        day++;
    }

    return -1;
}

public static String getTimeString() {
    int daysTillActivation = getDaysTillActivation();

    if (daysTillActivation == 0) {
        return "Active";
    }

    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.now(z);
    ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ZonedDateTime.now(z).plusDays(daysTillActivation).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    
    long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between( zdtStart , zdtStop );
    return formatDuration(millis);
}
```

It works, for *now*.
But before I use it in some sort of "production", I would like to hear some advises on what could be better, or what it could break...

Here's my general Idea:
I want to have a feature be enabled only every 2 days, therefore I would like to display to the user how much time is left for it to be enabled

For Example:

- Mon 30.Jan - Enabled
- Thu 31.Jan - Disabled
- Wed 1.Feb - Disabled
- .... - Enabled

As you can see, I don't mind if they have multiple days off. That's why I went with simply checking if the current day is dividable by 2.

However, this code will run every second and I just want to make sure I get everything right/get the best performance out of it.

Comment: Make sure you do not need the software enabled in order to uninstall.  There are still quite a few packages out there which cannot be uninstalled once the licence has expired.

Comment: Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API — `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime` and `ChronoUnit` belong there — you should use java.time exclusively and not mix in the `Calendar` class, which is cumbersome and error-prone to use, poorly designed and long outdated. You may also use `Duration` from java.time for a duration.

Comment: Why are you mixing `java.util.Date/Calendar` and `java.time`? Stick to one (ie `java.time`).

Comment: Isn’t this question better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about Code Review Stack Exchange. I will use it in the future.

Comment: I will change it up

Comment: Your `getDaysTillActivation` method is hard to read, and after reading it twice I still don’t think I have understood how it works. I think I’d add 1 day to `zdtStart`, and if I end up on the 1st of a month (or on an odd date, those conditions will be equivalent), add one more day.

Comment: Also you have a potential bug from reading the clock twice: If `Calendar.getInstance()` is called just before midnight on the 4th (an enabled day), there will of course be 0 days until enabled. If `ZonedDateTime.now(z)` is then called just after midnight on the 5th, your method will tell me there is 0 time (or a small negative amount of time) until enabled, which is not true.

Comment: why the loop in `getDaysTillActivation`? the method will always return only `0` or `1`, the loop will be repeated at most once... why not just `return day % 2`?

Comment: @user16320675 That's not true, as in the example I mentioned in my thread, it is possible that it returns 2. Well that could be the new maximum as well, but the loop will not continue anyway, so I just left it there

Comment: sorry, I can not see how that method is returning `2` - if `day` is even it will return `0` from first iteration (`i=0`); if odd, `day` will be incremented and it will return `1` on second iteration (`i=1`), since now `day` is even (incrementing an odd number by one, makes it even) - can you give an example for which date it will return `2`?

Comment: just to be clear, I meant the result of the `getDaysTillActivation()` method! I also can not see how the example in the question mentions anything about "*it returns 2*"

Comment: @user16320675 So kindly asked, you would think it only takes 1 day to get from the 30th of any month to the 1st of the next month, while having a 31th'st day in the base month? 31 and 1 are both numbers not dividible by 2

Comment: no idea what you are saying now. You stated that what I wrote is "*not true*"! So. please, give an example when mentioned method returns something that is not either `0` nor `1`! That it is not just returning the same as `day % 2` without the need of any loop!

Comment: seems like there is no proof for "*it is possible that it returns 2.*" - so you called me a liar, but without proving it :-(